# Toggle pass by reference parameter based on template type C++

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

I am implementing a "starts_with" function to check if a string starts with some prefix. I want the function to be able to compare `std::string` and `std::string_view` interchangeably. The issue I'm running into is when a `std::string` is passed as an argument I want it to be passed by reference and a `std::string_view` to be passed by value.

Currently I have this setup:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template <typename String>
struct string_type {
  using type = const String&;
};

template <>
struct string_type<std::string_view> {
  using type = const std::string_view;
};

template <typename String>
using string_type_t = typename string_type<String>::type;

template <typename String, typename Prefix>
bool string_starts_with(string_type_t<String> str, string_type_t<Prefix> pre) {
  if (pre.length() > str.length()) {
    return false;
  }

  for (auto ch = std::pair{str.begin(), pre.begin()};
       ch.second != pre.end();
       ++ch.first, ++ch.second) {
    if (*ch.first != *ch.second) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

int main() {
  using namespace std::string_view_literals;

  return string_starts_with("hello"sv, "hel"sv) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

However gcc and clang (tested [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jb1Pf4)) are unable to deduce the template parameters and I have to specify the types explicitly `string_starts_with<std::string_view, std::string_view>(..., ...)`.

One obvious solution would be to provide overloads for `std::string_view` but then I need to implement 4 different functions with essentially the same body (`string_starts_with(std::string, std::string)`, `string_starts_with(std::string, std::string_view)`, `string_starts_with(std::string_view, std::string_view)`, `string_starts_with(std::string_view, std::string)`). This might still be manageable but what if there is another string-like object such as `std::vector<char>` or `std::array<char>` that I want to introduce to the API it just becomes unmanageable.

Comment: Why not just take `std::string_view` parameter at all times? It's implicitly constructible from `std::string`

Comment: As @IgorTandetnik says, just a `string_view` would do. This is also what the STL does for `starts_with`.

Comment: Completely forgot about that! I guess for other string-like objects I can just construct a `string_view` in the function call.

Comment: Wouldn't `template <typename String, typename Prefix> bool string_starts_with(const String& str, const Prefix& pre) { ...` work for `string_view`s too? Why do you need to have it passed by value?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I believe that since `string_view` is simply a pointer to the start and a size it can be packed into 2 registers (at least on some ABI's) and therefore no indirection occurs and the compiler can optimize the code better.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for picking that up, I fixed it in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading it wrong actually :-) Forget that comment. It's `ch.first != str.end()` that can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting a type-aliase disables deduction. Because the compiler has no way to guess which class the nested parameter is possibly defined in. You can define a traits template and/or use meta-programming constructs (`enable_if`, `if constexpr`, `concept/requires`, `static_assert`...) to constraint the template:

```
template<typename > 
struct str_ref_traits: std::false_type{};
template<>
struct str_ref_traits<std::string&>: std::true_type{};
template<>
struct str_ref_traits<std::string_view>: std::true_type{};

template <typename S, typename P>
bool string_starts_with(S str, P pre) {
    static_assert(str_ref_traits<S>::value);
    static_assert(str_ref_traits<P>::value);
    if (pre.length() > str.length())
        return false;
    return std::equal(begin(pre), end(pre), begin(str));
};
```

Of course as mentioned in the comments, `std::string_view` can handle `std::string` - by design. But I wanted to mention the general rule that nested type-aliase cannot be deduced.
In fact, the design goal of `std::type_identity` is to be used as a deduction disabler on purpose.

regards,
FM.